# Error al aplicar plugin Material Theme UI en Intllij idea

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

Tengo instalado el plugin Material  Teme UI en mi IDE, Intellij. Este plugin lo que hace es aplicar un tema a la interfaz de forma integral (aplicando los cambios tanto en el color de la sintaxis como en las ventanas y/o panales del editor.

El problema que tengo es en la parte donde me muestra la estructura del programa que estoy haciendo (es una ayuda que permite ver de forma más gráfica los métodos, variables etc. de tu programa), y es que los íconos, de por ejemplo: los métodos y clases no se muestran como debieran

En la primera imagen muestro, señalando con el color verde cómo deberían verse los íconos señalados en rojo de la segunda imagen.

¿Se puede solucionar?
¿Cómo?

[image: Antes de aplicar el plugin]
[image: Después de aplicar el plugin]

Comment: Creo que eso es error del plugin, podrías publicarlo en su pagina oficial o en algún foro de intellij.